# Method returns a ParentClass object which can be one of two ChildClass types. How can I expose the ChildClass properties?

Tags: c#, list, inheritance, parent-child

Per the code below, I have a GetOrderPreviewSecurity() method that returns a Security, which is a parent class to Stock and MutualFund.

The GetOrderPreviewSecurity() method only actually returns a Stock type or MutualFund type to a Security property. The issue I'm having is trying to access the Child-specific properties as described in the //comments below.

Is there a way I can force the cast or clean this up that is cleaner than "var newThing = (ChildClass)SecurityClass;" and using newThing?

```
public class Stock : Security
{
   public string Ask;
   public string Bid;
}

public class MutualFund : Security
{
   public string AssetClass;
   public string Category;
}

public Security PreviewSecurity;

  public Security GetOrderPreviewSecurity(_orderTickerText){
     //Do stuff
     if (boolean thing)
        return new Stock();
     else if (boolean thing)
        return new MutualFund();
     else
        return new Security("empty");
  }

//Some stuff

        private void ExecutePreviewOrder()
        {            
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_orderTickerText) && _orderShareQuantity > 0)
            {   
                //Returns a **Security**
                PreviewSecurity = _portfolioService.GetOrderPreviewSecurity(_orderTickerText);

                if (PreviewSecurity is Stock)
                {
                    //PreviewSecurity is still a Security type. 
                    //No Bid or Ask properties available
                    PreviewBid = PreviewSecurity.Bid; 
                    PreviewAsk = PreviewSecurity.Ask;

                }
                else if (PreviewSecurity is MutualFund)
                {
                    //PreviewSecurity is still a Security type.
                    //No AssetClass or Category propeties available 
                    PreviewAssetClass = PreviewSecurity.AssetClass;
                    PreviewCategory = PreviewSecurity.Category;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Try [`as`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx):  `PreviewSecurity as Stock`, `PreviewSecurity as MutualFund`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a set of parentheses around the entire thing, like this:

```
if (PreviewSecurity is Stock)
{
    PreviewBid = ((Stock)PreviewSecurity).Bid;
    PreviewAsk = ((Stock)PreviewSecurity).Ask;
}
else if (PreviewSecurity is MutualFund)
{
    PreviewAssetClass = ((MutualFund)PreviewSecurity).AssetClass;
    PreviewCategory = ((MutualFund)PreviewSecurity).Category;
}
```

I think the issue is that the dot has higher precedence than the cast operator, so first the dot operator is applied, and then the cast operator is applied to whatever is returned by the dot operator.

Comment: That did it! Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see any problem with casting the Security back once you have type checked it.

```
if (PreviewSecurity is Stock)
{
    PreviewBid = (Stock)PreviewSecurity.Bid; 
    PreviewAsk = (Stock)PreviewSecurity.Ask;
}
else if (PreviewSecurity is MutualFund)
{
    PreviewAssetClass = (MutualFund)PreviewSecurity.AssetClass;
    PreviewCategory = (MutualFund)PreviewSecurity.Category;
}
```

Comment: I agree I think that should work, too. For some reason my compiler isn't having it.

Comment: Some parenthesis problem I am overlooking?